# looking for a haiku maybe written by Sasaki Sadako

Tags: poetry, haiku

I'm looking for the Japanese text of the following [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku), maybe written by [Sasaki Sadako](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadako_Sasaki) :

> Statute of A-bomb child
>
> she seems as if walking
>
> after a butterfly

I found the English text [here](http://war-haiku.tempslibres.org/poets/ys.html). The author may be Sasaki Sadako (see the mention "Sadoka Sasaki - a thousand of cranes") or Yasuhiko Shigemoto (but I don't see this haiku [in the texts written by this author and available online](http://www.fureai-ch.ne.jp/%7Ehaiku/)).

I guess "Statute of A-bomb child" is the translation of ["原爆の子の像"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Peace_Monument) (seven [morae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_(linguistics))).

Comment: Where does it say it was written by Sasaki?

Comment: @l'électeur : you're right, I updated my question.

Comment: Looking at the page, I think the best place to look for a Japanese original might be in Yasuhiko Shigemoto's books わたしのヒロシマ俳句「My Haiku of Hiroshima」 (Vol. 1 or 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Disclaimer: This might crush your dream.]

First of all, here are the facts - if I can trust Wiki, that is.

The haiku in question could ***not*** have been written by 佐々木禎子{ささきさだこ}.  Why not?  That is because Sasaki died in **1955** and the statue was completed in **1958** to commemorate Sasaki and other kids.  Sasaki simply could not have written a poem inspired by the statue as she never saw it herself.

Secondly, my gut feeling as a Japanese-speaker more than anything.  (That means you can take it or leave it.)

It would be safe to say that the haiku was written by 重本泰彦{しげもとやすひろ} though I could not find it anywhere online and ***it was written in English in the first place***.  Thus, there exists no such thing as the Japanese original.  Shigemoto seems to have written many haiku in English.